# Why does lazy loading angular modules create extra chunk default~customer-customer-module~order-order-module?

Tags: angular

My app contains 5 modules- `CoreModule`, `SharedModule`, `UserModule`, `CustomerModule` and `OrderModule`. `UserModule`, `CustomerModule` and `OrderModule` are lazy loaded modules.

When I `ng server` the app, it was supposed to generate 3 chunks - `user-user-module`, `customer-customer-module` and `order-order-module`.

But it is creating another extra chunk `default~customer-customer-module~order-order-module` along with those three chunks.

Now run the app in localhost, open Network tab of Developer tools:

1. navigate to `UserModule`, `user-user-module.js` is loaded.
2. navigate to `CustomerModule`, `default~customer-customer-module~order-order-module.js` and `customer-customer-module.js` are loaded.

My queries are:

1. Why is Angular CLI creating that extra chunk `default~customer-customer-module~order-order-module` ?
2. When navigate to `UserModule`, only `user-user-module.js` is loaded. But why `default~customer-customer-module~order-order-module.js` and `customer-customer-module.js` are being loaded when navigate to `CustomerModule` ?

I need to know what may be the causes. I cannot share my source code. Please give your opinionated answer.

**Angular version:** 7.3.9.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a feature of webpack known as [split-chunks](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/)

It generated a shared bundle of dependencies that are used both in your customer module and order module.

Comment: great, could you also accept the answer please :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers